# Using sample_weight for keras Recurrent Neural Network

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm looking at passing in an argument to `sample_weight` in my keras `.fit()` method in order to control the weighting my input neurons have on the model output. For example, I'm working on a Recurrent Neural Network where my data pipeline has a window size of 4 and 2 features. So my original input is a `(4, 2)` matrix.

According to the [keras docs](https://keras.io/api/models/model_training_apis/):

> sample_weight: Optional Numpy array of weights for the training
> samples, used for weighting the loss function (during training only).
> You can either pass a flat (1D) Numpy array with the same length as
> the input samples (1:1 mapping between weights and samples), or in the
> case of temporal data, you can pass a 2D array with shape (samples,
> sequence_length), to apply a different weight to every timestep of
> every sample. This argument is not supported when x is a dataset,
> generator, or keras.utils.Sequence instance, instead provide the
> sample_weights as the third element of x.

Since I am using `tf.data` I have to pass in the `sample_weight` as the third element of x as per the docs. I am confused about what the shape of the 2D/3D array should be for my `sample_weight`.

For example, when I use `batch_size` my input is of size `(batch_size, window_size, features)`. As per the docs, I have to feed in a 2D array of shape `(samples, sequence_length)`. I want to have the same weighting for all samples, but change it for my `window_size` and `features`.

So does that mean `sample_weight` should be of size `(batch_size, window_size, features)`? Again I want to have the same weighting for each `sample`, therefore would the following be correct for a `batch_size` of 3, a `window_size` of 5 and a `features` of 2? (Note: it is the same for each batch, which is what I want)

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 5, 2), dtype=float32, numpy=
 array([[[0.   , 0.   ],
         [0.25 , 0.025],
         [0.5  , 0.05 ],
         [0.75 , 0.075],
         [1.   , 0.1  ]],
 
        [[0.   , 0.   ],
         [0.25 , 0.025],
         [0.5  , 0.05 ],
         [0.75 , 0.075],
         [1.   , 0.1  ]],
 
        [[0.   , 0.   ],
         [0.25 , 0.025],
         [0.5  , 0.05 ],
         [0.75 , 0.075],
         [1.   , 0.1  ]]], dtype=float32)>)
```

---

### Edit

The example displays the error:

```
ValueError: Can not squeeze dim[2], expected a dimension of 1, got 2 for '{{node huber_loss/weighted_loss/Squeeze}} = Squeeze[T=DT_FLOAT, squeeze_dims=[-1]](IteratorGetNext:2)' with input shapes: [?,5,2].
```

Comment: What do you mean by channels? is that the feature dimension?

Comment: @thushv89, yes. Although it doesn't change the question if I had additional dimensions.

Comment: Can't you just weigh the inputs in your data pipeline instead of trying to do this within the rnn? That'd be much easier

Comment: @thushv89, if it were much easier then you could have easily provided an answer. But the reality is its not. You can't just scale the inputs at the beginning, you need to add a matrix at the end feeding into the final layer as a weight matrix (that's how its already done in keras using `sample_weight`). I would have to use a lambda layer at the end, but again, keras has the tools to do it, I'm asking if anyone understands how to use it properly.